# Facebook api - user still logged after close browser

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I have a problem with facebook connect in my application. I use PHP SDK and JS SDK.

When user log in with facebook to my web-app (without remember me function on Facebook), close browser and start it again. He is still as logged when I call ->getUser() and ->api('/me') and he shouldn't. I searched and try all possible solution, and nothing works. Problem is problem because of facebook cookies fbm_APPID a fbsr_APPID, which are set by Facebook and expire after two hours. When I destroy this cookies, they recreate automaticly...

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Try calling `FB.logout()` upon onUnload window close event.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but when user go to the other website, and close browser, problem is still there.

Comment: In any of my 55 facebook apps, when I call FB.logout(), I cannot again access FB.api('/me') without having the user come back and log back into facebook.